# What does ‘es soll’ in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verb

> *Loftus Hall* – ein jahrhundertealter Herrschaftsitz in dem es spuken soll.

I take it to mean ‘it is supposed to be haunted’. Is my interpretation of the meaning of *es soll* in this context correct?

Comment: I reckon this is rather about http://loftushall.ie/ than about http://loftushall.de/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Es soll* can mean two things:

- Something *is supposed to do/be* something. Example: *Das Boot ist nicht hochseetauglich. Es soll nur auf Binnenseen fahren*.
- Something *is rumoured/said to be* something. Example: *Es soll ja abends früher dunkel werden.*

In your case, the second meaning is used.

The German verb *spuken* means *to haunt* or *to spook*. As opposed to English, where *something is haunted*, in German it *spukt* **somewhere**.

So the literal translation of your sentence is

> ... a centuries old aristocratic estate **in which it is said to spook**

The location which is said to be haunted must be given in dative case. Examples for other verbs are:

> Das Haus, **in dem** er wohnt
>   Das Auto, **mit dem** er fährt
>   Die Wohnung, **in der** er lebt

The same goes for the verb *spuken*:

> Das Haus, **in dem** es spukt

Please note that the context is sometimes a bit hard to see. Take this example:

> Ein Gespenst soll spuken.

Without further context it is not possible to decide which of the above given meanings of *es soll* is meant here. Do you want to say that a ghost is supposed to spook or that a ghost is said to spook (here)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is extremely comprehensive. My sentence is a quotation from an article about a castle in which it is believed there is a ghost. 'Said to spook' sounds correct.

Comment: Your original idea to translate it as "which is said to be haunted" is correct given the grammatical differences between *spuken* and *to haunt*.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is more of "it is said to be haunted". It does not have that connotation that it *has* to be haunted as "it is supposed to be haunted".

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for unanswered questions on how it works.

Comment: That was my understanding too. Thank you for your comment.